# Animation on a button during an ajax call. But when it takes but little?

Tags: javascript, ajax, user-experience

I have a button on an html page. I click on it and an ajax call gets sent. The text on a button gets replaced with animated dots while a call is in progress.
The problem is that sometimes a call takes several seconds, and sometimes 0.5 or 1 second.
**When it takes 0.5 or 1 second, UX becomes bad because the text on a button gets replaced with animated dots and then it returns. A user sees 2 blinks happenning too fast.**

How can I improve this?

Comment: Instead of _instantly_ replacing the dots as soon as the call is finished, set a timeout such that the dots will exist for at least X seconds, to avoid a rapid flash.

Comment: ...Or maybe you should use CSS styles to make the button fixed width?

Comment: Man, you got 3 answers to your question and you've commented to each of them that `You didn't understand my question`. Don't you think your question needs some clarifications in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this as your submit event handler. It'll finish animation immediately if a given amount of time has passed. If it hasn't, it'll wait that amount of time before finishing up.

```
let button_pressed = (e)=>{
    let button = document.getElementById('button_id');
    button.ajaxStarted = new Date().valueOf();

    animate_waiting(); // start your dot animation effect

    var XHR;
    XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    XHR.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){ // done
            let diff = new Date().valueOf() - document.getElementById('button_id').ajaxStarted;
            if(diff < (1000 * 3)){ // three seconds have not yet passed
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    call_finished(); // now finish animating and post content
                }, (1000 * 3) - diff);
            }else{ // three seconds have passed
                call_finished(); // now finish animating and post content
            }
        }
    }
    XHR.open("GET", "/your_ajax_call?foo=bar", true);
    XHR.send();
}
```

Comment: What if status isn't 200? Or request times out?

Comment: I'm sure OP can handle different statuses however they like.

Comment: I'm not asking how to show animation. You didn't understand my question.

Comment: Can you clarify the question @tajara? I was under the impression the issue was the UI snapping from 'loading' to 'finished' too fast. "UX becomes bad" is a bit vague unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join your request call with some timeout function and wait till both complete. The implementation on pure JS could look as follows:

1. Wrap your xhr request into a Promise

```
var makeRequest = function (url, method) {

    // Create the XHR request
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Return it as a Promise
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        // Setup our listener to process compeleted requests
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {

            // Only run if the request is complete
            if (request.readyState !== 4) return;

            // Process the response
            if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) {
                // If successful
                resolve(request);
            } else {
                // If failed
                reject({
                    status: request.status,
                    statusText: request.statusText
                });
            }

        };

        // Setup our HTTP request
        request.open(method || 'GET', url, true);

        // Send the request
        request.send();

    });
};
```

2. Create some waiting function

```
var justWait = function(interval) {
   return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, interval);
   })
}
```

3. Use them together

```
// apply animation here
Promise.all([
    makeRequest('https://some/url/here', 'GET'),
    justWait(1000)
]).then(res => {
    // remove animation here
})
  .catch(err => {
    // remove animation here also in case of error
  });
```

This will guaranty that your animation would be at least as long as `justWait` interval but if the xhr request takes longer - it will wait untill it's finished.

If you are using `rxjs` library you can use `zip` instead of `Promise.all` however the general idea remains the same.

Comment: I'm not asking how to show animation. You didn't understand my question.

Comment: I think I did. Your problem is when the request is finished too fast the animation just blinks. You need to find a way to make animation took at least one second for example. My post gives you this example. If I'm still wrong please, concretize because as I see on other posts - other users understood your question the same.